# iPhone Crash Log: how to figure out what is wrong

Tags: iphone, uikit, crash, cydia

I'm not a developper, but a user of an iPhone (3GS, iOS 4.1, Jailbroken) which started to crash randomly last week on several app. If I'm right, it crashes randomly when I tap on the keyboard (texting, sending an email, search on Google...), so that's why the crash happens on several app I guess.

By crashing I mean:
- Either, the app close itself (Safari.app, Mail.app...)
- Or, the SpringBoard crash and the iPhone go on SafeMode

What I did before it started to crash:
- Weeks ago, I installed a Cydia Tweak to setup a Frecnh Keyboard, tweak I uninstalled after it started to crash, thinking it was because of it, but apparently it wasn't
- I installed a .deb manually with Cydia, everything went well
- I modified the /dpkg/status file in order to prevent Cydia from asking me for an app update, everything went well too (besides some description line which I had to delete)

Here are 2 Crash Log:
http://pastie.org/private/nuncku1absv3frk5f4tva

http://pastie.org/private/1lc9lfbhdagkynhsmwm6w

=> They talk about UIKit, does anybody know what is wrong and what should I do to fix the crash? I tried to look for on Google, bu I didn't find anything unfortunately...

Thank you very much for your help!

Thomas

Comment: restore your iphone to get rid of the jailbreak. That's all you can do. As a developer I can tell you that users with jailbreaks send much more mails with complaints about bugs. And when I see PhotoMail, bitesms, foldercloser or anything else that shouldn't be there in a crashreport I reply with kind words how I can't debug bugs that may be caused by jailbreaks. Apps crash, my apps crash too. But if my app crashes it's only my app that crashed. If one of your cydia tweaks crash it crashes everything.

Answer (score 1):

Correct answer:

Get the package "Crashreporter" from Cydia (BigBoss Repo).

For Springboard crashes, you can ignore the warning at first start.

Select the most recent crashlog, wait a moment for the analysis.

The most likely suspect for the crash will be displayed first.

Get rid of that package, and retry.

Comment: Can you provide details how to get this crash reporter. I searched on google but  could not find from where to install it and on what to install?